# How To Customise WordPress Comment Submit Button

Tags: wordpress, comments, styles

I am trying to customise the output code of

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

At the moment the submit button outputs the following:

```
<p class="form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Comment">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="486" id="comment_post_ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</p>
```

I would like it to output the following:

```
<div class="darkbutton" onclick="document.commentform.submit()">
    <span class="darkbutton-left"></span><a href="javascript: submitform()">Log In</a>  
    <span class="darkbutton-right"></span>
</div>
```

so as the completely restyle the button. Now I know it could be done by editing the core Wordpress files in comment-template.php but I really don't want to have to do this if there is any other way.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 7):

Have a trick

```
.form-submit{display: none;}
```

You can following after

```
$args = array(
 'comment_notes_after' => '<button type="submit" id="submit-new"><span>'.__('Post Comment').'</span></button>' 
);
comment_form($args);
```

Comment: See also this change, which landed 3 days ago: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/29809

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add a class to form tag and the submit button. I don't know where I found it, but this solution helped me out. You have to modify the str_replace to suite your needs.

```
ob_start(); 
comment_form($comments_args, $post_id);
$form = ob_get_clean(); 
$form = str_replace('class="comment-form"','class="comment-form my-class"', $form);
echo str_replace('id="submit"','class="btn btn-warning"', $form);
```

Comment: Clever hack that gets the job done. I just can't believe what a pain it is to customize the comment form of a blogging platform.

Answer (score 1):

Wrodpress has "[Pluggable Functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions)" That allow you to overwrite some core functions. This is useful because they won't overwrite your changes when upgrading and such. However, it does not look like the `comment_form()` is one of them.

If you're looking to avoid modifying core files, why not just edit your template file to output your desired code instead of calling the `comment_form()` function? Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you're just going to have to modify that file.

Comment: I would happily do that but I have no idea what the actual full output code is!

Comment: There are heaps of hooks and filters to modify the comment form defaults http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/21/using-the-wordpress-comment-form

Comment: @BradDalton and can you please point out where in that post it says how to add either a button class or the `<button>` selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can read some discussion about this issue [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15015), but it doesn't look like any fixes have been made to the WP codebase.

For now, I'm making style changes to my button on client side with jQuery. You could generate your `<div>` block with jQuery, and then hide their `form-submit` block by doing this:

```
.form-submit {
    display: none;
}
```

This isn't foolproof code, but it's a hack that will work until they implement something better.